# jQuery animate element and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building Windows 8 app in JavaScript. What I'm trying to do is to slide the html element out of the screen and then change its "display" property to "none":

```
var panelContainer = $('#panelContainer');
panelContainer.animate({ right: '-400px' }, 200, function () {
    panelContainer.hide();
});
```

But this code doesn't work correctly: it just immediately hides the element without animation.
I've also tried:

```
var panelContainer = $('#panelContainer');
panelContainer.animate({ right: '-400px' }, 200, function () {
    panelContainer.hide(200);
});
```

and it works, but it's a hack: I don't want to change the opacity when animating and I don't need to have additional timeout for hiding.
I've found that jQuery UI library has extended show and hide methods that do that, but I would like not to reference this library just for one call. I'm aware that there is a WinJS.UI.Flyout that performs similar operation, but it's not applicable in my case. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Maybe 200ms is just too fast. Try slower, like 700ms.

Comment: Seems to work correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/VeggV/ - Can you show any relevant CSS?

Comment: `right` only has an effect when the element has a `position` style property other than the default `static`.

Comment: I would say that I don't need even 200ms because I want to hide it right when the animation is done. Putting 700ms only increases the delay.

Comment: I think what Joseph meant was the animation speed. 0.2 seconds is pretty fast, and the animation will be barely noticeable?

Comment: I agree that the longer animation will be almost invisible, but it's still a hack.. I want the code to work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsN5g/ But the same code just hides the element in win8 app. Is there any other way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that jQuery does not put `hide` animation into its animation queue by default. That's why my initial code was hiding the html element first and then animating it. The solution for that is to call hide with the parameter that explicitly specifies that `hide` call should be queued:

`panelContainer.hide({queue: true});`